# Display the select file

Tags: r

I have written a code to read csv or excel file in shiny app. But what is happening is that, whatever I select first (say Excel file), the output is displayed. But once I switch to other (csv) the excel is still there and csv is not displayed. Not sure what wrong is there in the code. Could anyone please help me?

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Loading data"),
dashboardSidebar(fileInput("datafile","Choose the csv file",multiple = TRUE, 
                           accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")),
                   ("Or"),
                 fileInput("datafile1","Choose the excel file",multiple = TRUE, 
                           accept = c(".xlsx"))),
dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(box(uiOutput("filter_70"),width = 5000))
))

server <- function(input,output){
output$contents <- renderTable({
  file_to_read <- input$datafile
  if(is.null(file_to_read))
     return(NULL)
     read.csv(file_to_read$datapath)
})
output$contents1 <- renderTable({
  file_to_read1 <- input$datafile1
  if(is.null(file_to_read1))
    return(NULL)
  read_excel(file_to_read1$datapath)
})

output$filter_70 <- renderUI(
  if (!is.null(input$datafile)) {
    tableOutput("contents")
  } else if (!is.null(input$datafile1)) {
    tableOutput("contents1")
  }
)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Even after you select `datafile1`, `datafile` is not null. So the if condition is still satisfied. If you want to display only one file at a time, you need to restructure your output

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by @Rohit, reactive value once gets selected, it won't go back to null.

Keep your main structure unchanged, all you need is to monitor which file last changed. This requires creating a reactiveVal (last_selected) and then use observeEvent to track.

```
  last_selected <- reactiveVal(NA)

  observeEvent(input$datafile, {
    last_selected("csv")
  })
  observeEvent(input$datafile1, {
    last_selected("excel")
  })
  output$filter_70 <- renderUI({
    req(last_selected())
    if (last_selected()=="csv") {
      tableOutput("contents")
    } else if (last_selected()=="excel") {
      tableOutput("contents1")
    }
  })
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. May I know what is the use of ````reactiveVal````

Comment: it's useful when you need a variable that doesn't come from a UI i.e. input$variable. Think it as a global variable living inside server function in the Shiny app because creating regular R variable is not allowed in the reactive context, you have to make it reactive.